# How do I clear a multidimensionl array

Tags: php

Sorry, it might be a very simple answer, but I have tried and took a look at google several times and I am disparing right now. I want to clear the following array ($list). Here is a print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
           [0] => 1 
           [1] => Tomato 
           [2] =>
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
           [0] => 
        ) 
      )
```

I want to get rid of `[2] =>`  after Tomato and the second value `[1] => Array ( [0] => )` There might be ten or more worts like Tomato.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not get the keys you do want and assign them to a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from comments below [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) documentation:

```
function array_filter_recursive($array, $callback = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
        }
        else {
            if ( ! is_null($callback)) {
                if ( ! $callback($value)) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( ! (bool) $value) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unset($value);

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function clear_array(&$array)
{
    foreach ( $array as $k=>$v )
    {
        if ( is_array($v) )
        {
            clear_array($array[$k]);
        } else if ( $v === '' || $v === null ) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```